# NodeJS: how to separate large strings into an array of numbers, and then add all of those with an even index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

The array I get my original strings from looks something like this:

```
arr[0]:
  11-3
  12-6
arr[1]:
  5-9
  7-2
  18-2
arr[2]:
  2-7
```

(That's just an example, the general idea is that there can be any number of objects in `arr` and the string in each of them contains any number of #-# combos)

I'm trying to add all the numbers on the left together (if using the example above it would add something like 11, 12, 5, 7, 18, and 2 together) and store that number in a variable.

How would I go about this?

**Edit 1: attempted code:**

```
var winsLossNums = winLoss[0].match(/\d+/g).map(Number)

for (var i = 0; i < winLoss[0].match(/\d+/g).map(Number).length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    totalNums.push(winLoss[0].match(/\d+/g).map(Number)[i]);
  }
}
}
```

This code is in a loop, and every loop there is a new `arr` object like in the example above

Comment: I edited some code in, sorry

Comment: I can't really tell what's going on with your array. Are those multiline strings with dashes? Can you include the quotes and make it valid JS or JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array values are strings with a new line between them, you can reduce over the array, split each value on `\n` and reduce again on that taking the first value of splitting on '-':

```js
let arr = ['11-3\n12-6', '5-9\n7-2\n18-2',  '2-7']

let tot = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    let pairs = c.split('\n')
    return a + pairs.reduce((a, c)=> a + Number(c.split('-')[0]), 0)
}, 0)

console.log(tot)
console.log(11 + 12 + 5 + 7+ 18 + 2)
```

You might need to clean up data or split on whitespace if it's not cleanly one `\n` per line. But this should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let arr = [
      [
        '11-3',
        '12-6'
      ], [
        '5-9',
        '7-2',
        '18-2'
      ], [
        '2-7'
      ]
    ];

    let sum = 0;
    for (let index=0; index<arr.length; index++) {
        let arrayMasterElement = arr[index];
        // console.log(arrayMasterElement);
        for (let index2=0; index2<arrayMasterElement.length; index2++) {
          let arrayElement = arrayMasterElement[index2];
          let elementArray = arrayElement.split('-');
          let intVal = parseInt(elementArray[0]);
          console.log('Int value: ' + intVal);
          sum += intVal;
        }
        if (index == arr.length - 1) {
            console.log('Sum: ' + sum);
        }
    }
```